# Is it ok to use "aluminium" in an otherwise American English text?

Tags: word-choice, language

I am not an American English native (I'm actually a German native speaker) but, when I write, I use the American style of words predominantly. However, I always use **aluminium** instead of **aluminum**, following the nomenclature that is used by all the rest of the world save for the US and Canada. It is also was the only valid IUPAC name between 1990 and 1993, since when aluminum is allowed as an *acceptable variant*<sup>1</sup>, but IUPAC publications strive to use the official aluminium variant.

Is it ok to break with AE and choose the BE/international version with this one word only (in a non-scientific text)?

Non-scientific means in this context any text that is not a scientific publication, among others fiction or blog posts.

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1 - Connelly, Neil G.; Damhus, Ture, eds. (2005): *Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry: IUPAC recommendations 2005*, p249: Table I *Names, symbols and atomic numbers of the elements (see also Section IR-3.1)*</sup>

> Name           Symbol  Atomic Number
> aluminium<sup>a</sup>       Al               13

<sup>In said table's footnotes:</sup>

> a: *the alternative spelling aluminum is commonly used*

---

This is not [British / American language mishmash](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/41440/british-american-language-mishmash) as this one just aims at one specific instance of one specific term and not a general "mix and match". This one case also is not looked at in the other question.

Comment: Is your text following the other sources where "aluminium" is predominately used?

Comment: FWIW, this is a *very hard difference to spot* in written text - your readers might not even notice unless you draw attention to it. (I speak BrE, and when reading the Mistborn trilogy by AmE writer Brandon Sanderson, in which the word aluminium is used a lot, I got as far as book 3 before even noticing the "aluminum" spelling - and when I did notice, I assumed it was a typo until noticing even later that it was *consistently* spelled that way.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor For a Canadian perspective, I didn't even realize that there were two spellings until I was much older than I would care to admit.  I always just thought there as a weird pronunciation tick when some people called it "aluminium".  That "i" doesn't really stand out to me.  When I see either word I immediately just think of the element regardless.

Comment: 99% of your readers won't notice one way or anohter

Comment: Despite the standard existing, [isn't Aluminum the one that came first, and first coined after criticism of a previous version *and* in ***not*** in the US?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium#Etymology) Thus IUPAC claiming Aluminium being the "more right" one is just pointless gate-keeping?

Comment: @opa with that reasoning we would have to use/write the latin/greek variants. For example sulphur, hydragyrum, argentum and aurum fror S, Hg, Ar and Au. But all these are not allowable at all under either IUPAC or any dictionary. And IUPAC has the international right and duty of formalizing a language: Chemistry.

Comment: @Trish: I got very confused - Sulphur *is* what we use... Then I looked it up and found that much like aluminium it is spelt differently in different places! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Academic Copyeditor here)

I see no problems; you have a good justification. If this is your text (your blog, a self-published book), you're done, though you might want to add a footnote etc. to explain why you're using that spelling.

If someone else will publish the text, you should talk to your editor AND make a note in the text. Talk to the editor because they may or may not have liberty with house style, and if it's a multi-author volume or a journal, they will want to keep things consistent. Make a note because the copyeditor may or may not notice that this is deliberate, and may or may not change it – once you flag it as deliberate, they're likely to leave it alone, respectively you can change it back if you have the editor's backing.

Comment: Interestingly, Tolkien had to do something very similar for his spelling 'elven' instead of the then-common 'elfin' (as well as several other similar examples). Being a professor of philology, he knew better how the word should be spelled, and stood his ground. The form stuck.

Answer (score 28):

Since you have a real-world justification, why not use that same justification in your fictional setting?

If you want to make it a thing, have a character say "aluminum" and the other characters can eyeroll or correct as per their personalities.

You could also have your infodump characters be from an international organization, and thereby set the standard for communication.

You can also have the individual characters use the word they would be most comfortable with. I doubt readers would be confused any more than if you used "metre" or "colour". (I realize it is actually more than just a variant spelling, but there is little chance the meaning would be mistaken.)

My answer is the same for your narrator/narrative voice. Use what *you* feel is natural, or use the version that *empathizes with the MC*.

Comment: I'd be _less_ confused by "aluminium" than I would by "metre" or "colour". "Aluminium" is pronounced differently from "aluminum" so it's easy to understand why that word was used (the character--or at least the author--speaks that way). If "metre" was used in an otherwise American-English text, I'd have no idea why that spelling was chosen since the words are pronounced exactly the same way.

Comment: Of course, if it is fiction, and your American main character insists on saying "aluminium foil", you should be prepared for *readers* to eyeroll at the irritating character trait. (It would be slightly less weird if your main character is a chemist who's actually referring to the element rather than a beer can or other everyday item, and completely un-weird for a German writing a blog in their own voice.)

Comment: Similar to Daniel, I would find "aluminium" less jarring than "metre" - I don't read every letter of every word and likely wouldn't even notice the extra "i" in aluminium, whereas "metre" screams *British* to me.

Comment: This may be hard to pull off. I always read aluminum as alumnium. It took many seconds of eyeballing to figure out which one was which. I think you'd have to resort to something like *aloo-min-um* and *al-u-min-e-um* if the difference was narratively relevant.

Comment: As an European (Dutch) with English learned as a second language, 'colour' and 'meter' do look right. As does 'aluminium'. It is how the words meter/metre and aluminium/aluminum are spelled in my own language while colour is what I have learned in school. Non native speakers may have different 'normal' from native speakers.

Answer (score 18):

In a non-scientific text (or in a scientific text, for that matter,) you should really keep it consistent. If you're otherwise using British English, then 'Aluminium' will look perfectly normal, just like 'colour' or 'metre.' However, if you're writing in American English, it will look weird, just as 'colour' or 'metre' would in an otherwise-American text.

Unless you have some reason why the use of this spelling should actually be important to your story, using a spelling that is not consistent with the rest of your text will look jarring and will distract your reader from the story.

Of course, if you actually *want* the distinction to be important in your story, then that's another matter. In that case, you can have your characters draw attention to the difference and have them discuss the use of one variety over the other.

---

As a side note, mentioning that this spelling is 'only' used in the USA and Canada really doesn't help the argument much, as the same argument could be made for all of American English. And, even if being used against all of AmE, it's still a poor argument in light of the fact that around 40% of all English speakers and over two thirds of all native English speakers worldwide speak the American variety. Both the American spellings and the British ones are used by very large percentages of English speakers, so trying to dismiss either one is kind of silly. Just pick one or the other and then be consistent unless there's a good reason for the spelling to deviate from the accepted one in the dialect of your text.

Comment: It's true that "over two thirds of all native English speakers worldwide speak the American variety", but this is disingenuous, as there are plenty who speak *fluent English as their second language*. The total number of [English speakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_English-speaking_population) globally is 1.18 billion, with (in order) 283 million in the USA, 259 million within the European Union, 125 million in India, 92 million in the Philippines and 79 million in Nigeria. There are more English speakers in Germany (45 million) than in Canada (30 million)!

Comment: It's a bit harder to work out how many speak AmE. If I count the total English speakers in the main AmE-speaking countries - USA 283 million, Philippines 92m, Canada 30m (though some would argue Canadians speak *Canadian* English), Mexico 16m, Brazil 11m, others ~12m) I get a total of 445 million. That's still less than half the English speakers worldwide. The USA doesn't (yet) dominate our language ;-)

Comment: @Chappo I wasn't saying that over half of all _total_ English speakers speak AmE. I was just saying that it's kind of silly to say 'just' the U.S. and Canada use a particular spelling when that's over two thirds of all native speakers.

Comment: And the point I'm making is that over half of all English speakers do **not** use AmE spelling. But let's be specific: Canadians generally use *British* spelling, so do they spell it "aluminium"? If so, the numbers are even more strongly slanted against the AmE spelling being useful outside of the USA.

Comment: @Chappo This isn't exactly the strongest data point, but I'm Canadian and I would spell and pronounce "aluminum" the AmE way. In general, I'd say our pronunciation matches AmE, and our spelling is split somewhat inconsistently between the English variants.

Comment: @camerondm9 thanks, that resolves my ignorance! Out of interest, do Canadians think of themselves as using AmE, or are they more likely to insist that they have their own unique variant (i.e. Canadian English)? Or does it depend on context?

Comment: @Chappo You're right that less than half of all English speakers use the American dialect, but that doesn't contradict the point in my answer. I was just pointing out that it's kind of silly to dismiss the spellings used by 'only' a large percentage of all English speakers and a strong majority of all native speakers. It would be equally silly to dismiss the British spellings. One should just pick a dialect and then be consistent when writing.

Comment: @Chappo We would generally think of ourselves as using Canadian English. In some contexts/industries it will be closer to British English, and in others it will be closer to American English, but we have enough unique words, slang, and exceptions to the rules (from mashing the other English variants together) that our English is different from the other variants. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_English) for a list of some of our uniquenesses.

Comment: @camerondm9 Canadian generally uses the British spelling rules (or at least that's how they were teaching it like 10 years ago); but aluminum is a bit of the odd one out.  We use the "American" spelling for aluminum for some reason.  I'm totally okay with that though, since aluminum saves us a syllable while the usual spelling rules have no bearing on that.

Comment: @Chappo "It's true that "over two thirds of all native English speakers worldwide speak the American variety", but this is disingenuous, as there are plenty who speak fluent English as their second language" You make no case for how it's "disingenuous", especially since reirab first gave the percentage for all speakers. The term "disingenuous" is arguably a violation of the "be nice" rule.

Comment: @Acccumulation you're late on the scene. It was disingenuous because it was unnecessarily selective by excluding non-native speakers; Reirab & I exchanged additional comments (since deleted as no longer necessary) & came to a happy agreement. **I derived the percentage figure and Reirab added it as an edit**. I'm pleased that you take the Code of Conduct seriously. However, *disingenuous* means "not speaking the whole truth", which was a fair comment; if I delete that comment, the stats also get deleted and the rest of the exchange becomes meaningless.

Comment: @Acccumulation I've reviewed the remaining comments as a whole, as perhaps there was a case for deleting my first comment. But I don't think it breached the "be nice" rule, there are 5 upvotes for the comment, the stats are useful (and took me some time to compile), and all up I think the comment is better to be retained. If you disagree, I'm comfortable with you flagging it for a mod to independently review.

Comment: IMO the stats are a distraction from the point. The values are open to doubt and dispute because sources aren't given and global statistics would necessarily be aggregated from many national statistics which might not use the same definitions of *English speaker*, *native English speaker*, and *American English speaker* (if they even try to distinguish between dialects). I think it would improve the answer to remove "*in light of the fact that around 40% of all English speakers and over two thirds of all native English speakers worldwide speak the American variety*".

Comment: @PeterTaylor I added the 40% part due to the comments (I agree that that's a little questionable since, while the dialects spoken in the countries mentioned in the comments are closer to AmE than BrE, they're not exactly AmE.) The 2/3 part is definitely not in dispute as that's only counting Americans. I think that stat is useful to demonstrate the false premise implied by the bit of the question that talks about a particular spelling 'only' being used in the U.S. and Canada.

Comment: Re "*The 2/3 part is definitely not in dispute as that's only counting Americans*": maybe the numerator of that fraction is not in dispute (beyond a percent or so), but the denominator is a major problem. That's why I mentioned possible discrepancies in the definition of *native English speaker* between different sources.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  It's your story, so it's okay.  And I can't be the only American who wasn't all that aware of the difference and whose eyes gloss over the two (I can only see them as different now that you've pointed it out to me, though I was dimly aware before, and now I understand why Brits pronounce it so strangely).

Be aware though:

1. Your publisher may ask you to change it.  Fortunately, it's a super quick change to do globally no matter how long your work.
2. When an American looks at your text inside any program with a spellchecker, it lights up like a Christmas tree.

Answer (score 4):

It's a minor difference, so I wouldn't get hung up on it. If it's an issue for a publisher, it's easy to fix.
I do a similar thing with the word "gray", because the street I grew up on had the word "grey" included in it, meaning that I always spell it wrong according to American English. Nobody aside from Microsoft Word's spellchecker has ever given me trouble-- or, I suspect, even noticed.

Answer (score 3):

If it is a scientific article, or scientific text, then by all means use the most precise term. In this case that would be either Aluminium or Aluminum. Pick the one that you prefer and be consistent in your text.

If it is for fiction or a vulgarization essay, then unless you have other reasons to do so, use the term that your readers will find most fitting. In this case that would be Aluminum.

PS Note that precision and consistency in scientific writing is not negotiable.

Comment: "Aluminum" is perfectly acceptable in a formal scientific context. It is unambiguous and officially accepted by IUPAC (unlike other alternate spellings like "sulphur" and "cesium"), so it is no less precise than "aluminium". Although strictly speaking what's acceptable is up to the journal editor.

Comment: Fair enough. I disagree on the last sentence. It is not up to the editor to define nomenclature standards.

Comment: @NofP The nomenclature Standard is aluminium, any publication *by* IUPAC reads Aluminium. It is however *allowable* to use aluminum and not have it rejected by other agencies.

Comment: @Trish while I was taught to use Aluminium, following eyeballfrog comment I actually checked what are the common uses in the scientific chemistry community. It turns out that *acceptable* means synonym, and not *a lower standard*  https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/aluminum  https://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/phs/phs.asp?id=1076&tid=34 and https://scholar.google.co.uk/ gives ~300k results for aluminum in titles and ~180k for aluminium, with good peace for whatever *acceptable* means.

Comment: @Trish  PS just compare https://iupac.org/?s=aluminum  with https://iupac.org/?s=aluminium  .  At this point I would really stress that consistency is the important factor, whatever your decision

Comment: @NofP America was supposed to start using "Aluminium" (the name given to the element in 1812, by the person who discovered it) as part of a deal with the IUPAC in 1990, whereby the rest of the world agreed to call Element 16 "Sulfur" instead of "Sulphur" (from the Latin "Sulpur").  Within 3 years, the USA had already reneged on their end, and the IUPAC basically said "sod it" and listed it as a "variant"...

Comment: @Chronocidal yes, and we are in 2019 at the moment. Unless the text is set in a specific time period, or it talks about the origin of the term, then it does not matter what "it used to be".

Comment: @NofP My point was more that "acceptable" initially meant "we can't get them to follow the actual rules, so we'll have to make an exception", rather than commenting on which to use when writing idiomatic American English.

Comment: @chronocidal apologies, I misread your comment. I actually agree with you!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use aluminium since only the United States (more like Divided States right now) uses aluminum. I see aluminum as the least true variant. However, since I live in the totally great country of called the United States of America, my laptop always tries to "correct" my spelling of aluminium, to aluminum, the improper spelling in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

Aluminum comes from the word alumina and is the name chosen by the Humphry Davy in 1812 and published throughout the world. "Aluminium" only exists because Thomas Young misspelled it. It's not a color vs colour issue.

The US and Canada were fighting each other in a bloody war at the time, but they both received the correct spelling from across the Atlantic ocean.

Edit:

Aluminum is the One True Spelling of the word.

Comment: So to be clear, your answer to the question is, "no, it's never okay to use 'aluminium'"? Even though that's the spelling promoted by IUPAC?

Comment: This could be a very relevant comment, but it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @F1Krazy - Correct

Comment: According to my info, Thomas Young did 1812 a **deliberate decision** to propose the better sound of Aluminium. This spelling caught on better in the US and was used by virtually all US Scientists until the mid-1830s (at wich point aluminum became popular via culture and one dictionary) and was still dominant in science till 1895. IUPAC did explicitly *forbid* to use aluminum between 1990 and 1993.

Comment: Check out the wikipedia talk page archives for aluminum, if you want to blow a few hours reading a holy battle.  Neither side will ever admit they're wrong... especially the brits :)

Comment: GIF is pronounced with a soft G. The guy who literally invented it and named it has declared it so. And yet everyone uses a hard G. Soft G is the only "correct" pronunciation, but absolutely nobody who disagrees will ever accept it, so sometimes you just gotta accept the inevitable mispronunciation will become correct.

Comment: @barbecue: Beware of geeks bearing GIFs.  Although the namers of things should generally be given deference as to their pronunciation, both the word from which the acronym is derived ("graphics") and the normal word to which it is closest ("gift")  have hard G sound, and someone who is unfamiliar with the term but hears "gif" with a hard G would be far more likely to guess at the spelling than someone who hears "jif".  All rather difficult obstacles to overcome if trying to get people to take one's pronunciation seriously.